# Python not creating and writing to csv

Tags: python, csv

I am using Spyder and accessing the reddit API to get some data and write it to csv, when I print out the lines, everything works fine, but then the csv file just doesn't get created, I tried many things but nothing seems to work, and a very similar piece of code worked out fine and I got the csv file, so I have no idea what the problem is.

```
with open('finalplswork.csv', 'wb') as fl:
    writr = csv.writer(fl)   
    for subid in idsss:
        submission = r.get_submission(submission_id=subid)
        created_utc=submission.created_utc
        created_date_utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(created_utc)
        data=(subid, created_utc, created_date_utc)
        writr.writerow(data)
```

Comment: How are you running the file? Check the directory where this python file is located, not the directory you are running it from.

Comment: For me, I had a ":" in my output filename and it just died silently. Like no exceptions, no errors, everything ran just fine. But the file was simply not created. Took me a while to figure out lol.

Answer (score 3):

Your CSV **is** created, but you are using a relative file path.

You'd have to print `os.getcwd()` to know where it is being created, or set the current working directory to where you expect your file to appear.

Best to use an absolute file path instead:

```
with open('C:/full/path/to/your/documents/folder/finalplswork.csv', 'wb') as fl:
```

Comment: Good theory.  But one note: you do know where it is created: `os.getcwd()`.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Sure, but I strongly suspect that the CWD is somewhere in `C:\Python27`, not the best place to go spelunking for a lost CSV file..

Comment: Not to mention on Windows unless you are using an elevated prompt, you can't write to most directories in the main system drive (ie, the "C drive").

Answer (score 0):

I turned your code into a self-contained example:

```
with open('finalplswork.csv', 'wb') as fl:
    writr = csv.writer(fl)
    for subid in range(3):
        submission = 'foo'
        created_utc = 130000
        created_date_utc = 20130704
        data=(subid, created_utc, created_date_utc)
        writr.writerow(data)
```

It works fine:

```
$ cat finalplswork.csv 
0,130000,20130704
1,130000,20130704
2,130000,20130704
```

So your problem is not with the code you've shown here.

Comment: Yes, true, I just tried it in python on terminal as opposed to the Spyder IDE, and it worked, so I guess it is a Spyder bug. I will still accept your answer soon, or should I delete the question?

Comment: Don't delete your question, it's fine.  I'm not sure it's a Spyder bug--see Martijn's answer!